# Python - Merging two strings that overlap

Tags: python

I am looking into trying to create a full address, but the data I have comes in the form of:

```
Line 1                     | Line 2                   | Postcode
1, First Street, City, X13
1, First Street             First Street, City          X13 
1                           1, First Street, City, X13  X13
```

There are a few other permutations of how this data is created, but I want to be able to merge all this into one string where there is no overlap. So I want to create the string:
`1, First Street, City, X13`

But not `1, First Street, First Street, City, X13` etc.

How can I concat or merge these without duplicating data already there? There are also some cells like on the top line where there is no information past the first cell.

Comment: how do you decide what is a valid combination or are you sure words won't repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a plain text you can split your text with `\n` in order to get the line and split the lines with `,` to get the separate fields :

```
>>> s = """1, First Street, City, X13
... 1, First Street             First Street, City,          X13 
... 1                           1, First Street, City, X13  X13"""
>>> 
>>> lines = s.split('\n')
>>> 
>>> splitted_lines = [line.split(',') for line in lines]
```

*Note* that as a more pythonic way you can use `csv` module to read your text by specifying the comma `,` as the delimiter.

```
import csv
with open('file_name') as f:
    splitted_lines = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
```

Then you can use following list comprehension to get the unique fields in each column :

```
>>> import re
>>> ' '.join([set([set(re.split(r'\s{2,}',i)).pop() for i in column]).pop() for column in zip(*splitted_lines)])
'1  First Street  City'
```

Note that here you can get the columns using `zip()` function and then split the items with `re.split()` with regex `r'\s{2,}'` which split your string with 2 or more white-space, then you can sue `set()` to preserve the unique items.

Note : If you care about the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `set`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> 
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> ' '.join([d.fromkeys([set(re.split('\s{2,}',i)).pop() for i in column]).keys()[0] for column in zip(*splitted_lines)])
'1  First Street  City  X13'
```

Comment: Each of the contents are in different cells in a pandas table. So I need a way to merge the contents of the cells without repeating words.

Comment: @Abi You can read the table and put the rows in an iterable object like `splitted_lines` then put it in aforementioned list comprehension.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep I added and OrderedDict approach too, and missing `X13` was because of omitted delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing punctuation:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()


from string import punctuation
with open("test.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    print("".join(od.fromkeys(word.strip(punctuation) for line in f    
          for word in line.split())))

1 First Street City X13
```

If you have repeated words you won't be able to use the approach but based on your input there is no way to know what possible combination are possible bar the second line  actually being always intact in which case you would just need pull the second line.